# FHIR: Multiple Classes with same name in a Project using (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, hl7-fhir

I am attempting to generate c# classes of FHIR Resources, How handle Multiple classes with same name? For Example -> In Organization and Patient resources there are Composed classes with same name "Contact" and Contact is one Complex date Type too. etc... Please Help

```
http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/organization.html
http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/datatypes.html#Contact
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the XSD.exe tool is capable of doing this, your best bet maybe to manually nest those classes where this is a problem, and then using the serialization attributes (most notable XmlTypeAttribute) to change the name of the types in the XSD if at all necessary.

Please note that a completely generated set of classes is part of the .NET reference implementation for FHIR (http://www.github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api).  We'll soon have the class generator for this available as part of this project, including a set of support functions to serialize them correctly to FHIR XML and FHIR Json.

Comment: Oky Thanks Sir . I have Written OrganizationContact, PatientContact, EncounterLocation etc ...

Answer (score 0):

The full class name of organization contact is actually Organization.contact.